# Symfony2 translations without domain

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I want to be able to use the twig translator without having to set the **domain**. To keep my translations organized I put them inside the `Resources/translation` folder of my bundles. I don't want them all in one file. To do a translation in twig I need to do the following:

```
{{ 'myStringToTranslate'|trans({}, 'MyBundle') }}
```

Is there a way to always load bundle translations so that I could do the following:

```
{{ 'myStringToTranslate'|trans }}
```

Comment: Define your translations in `@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml` for example. Default domain name is called *messages*